# Erro #CS0176 no if statement, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: c#, métodos-estáticos

Por que estou recebendo o erro #CS0176 quando eu chamo a variável `madeiras` em `(gamble.Equals("gamble {0}", madeiras))`?

Pelo o que eu entendi é porque o meu método é estático, e preciso colocar o nome de sua classe, mas o erro persiste se eu colocar `(gamble.Equals("gamble {0}", Program.madeiras))`, por exemplo.

```
 namespace GambleGame
 {
    class Program
    {   
        //váriaveis em int
        static int madeiras = 0;

        //váriaveis em string
        static string gamble;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //método principal
            //...
            //Gamble Game
            //cor da intro
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; 
            
            //executa o método estático "intro"
            intro();
        }

        public static void intro()
        {
            //código do método estático intro
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------|||Seja bem vindo ao Gamble Game|||---------------------------");
           
            {  
                //cor das intruções
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("- Intruções:");     
            Console.WriteLine("- Digite ''gamble'' para farmar 10 madeiras");
            Console.WriteLine("- Para apostar ''X'' madeiras, digite ''apostar'' e o número de madeiras");
            Console.WriteLine("- Você poderá apostar ''X'' madeiras para ganhar a mesma quantidade");
            Console.WriteLine("- Porém, se você apostar ''X'' madeiras e perder, você perde essa mesma quantidade");
            Console.WriteLine("- Tente ser o maior lenhador dentre seus amigos, boa sorte !");
            Console.WriteLine("- Aperte Enter para começar !");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            start(); //executa o método estático "start"
        }

        public static void start()
        {
            {
                //cor do start
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            }

            // loop for(int loop = 0; loop < 999*999; loop++)
            //código do método start
            Console.WriteLine("Digite ''gamble'' para bater na árvore");
            Console.WriteLine("Você possui {0} madeiras", madeiras);

            bool loop = true;

            while (loop)
            {
                gamble = Console.ReadLine();

                if (gamble.Equals("gamble"))
                {
                    madeiras = madeiras + 10;
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite ''gamble'' para bater na árvore");
                }

                if (gamble.Equals("gamble {0}", madeiras))
                {
                    madeiras = madeiras + madeiras;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Você possui {0} madeiras", madeiras);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: coloque o código completo, com a declaração dos métodos

Comment: O que quer fazer com `"gamble {0}", madeiras` dentro do gamble.Equals()?

Comment: Foi colocado o código completo. Correto, ramaral.

Comment: Acho que se calhar o objetivo era fazer `gamble.Equals(string.Format("gamble {0}", madeiras))`.

Comment: Correto, João, já está funcionando agora, entendi o erro. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [erro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0176) é devido ao facto de a classe String ter um método estático com essa assinatura([public static bool Equals(string,string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx)) e estar a ser qualificado com um nome de instância.

Para o usar tem de o qualificar com o nome da classe:

```
String.Equals("gamble {0}", madeiras);
```

Isso irá comparar a string `"gamble {0}"` com o conteúdo da variável `madeiras`.

Pelo que é dado a entender não é o que você pretende, mas sim:

```
gamble.Equals(string.Format("gamble {0}", madeiras))
```

ou, melhor ainda, usando "interpolação de strings":

```
gamble.Equals($"Texto {madeiras}")
```

Comment: Não @ramaral, o problema está no facto de que a interpolação de strings estar incorreta, falta-lhe o `string.Format`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Eu sei, veja o meu comentário. No entanto estou a responder ao que foi perguntado: **Erro #CS0176 no if statement, o que estou fazendo de errado?**

Answer (score 4):

De cara vejo que o laço é infinito, inclusive usa uma variável sem necessidade. Precisa ver como sairá dele, duvido que seja esta a intenção.

Não é um erro, mas usar `Equals()` em C# não faz sentido (pode haver um contexto bem específico). Outras coisas podem ser modernizadas. Os comentários são bem desnecessários, acrescentam zero informação útil. O código é bem confuso e não usa padrão de nomenclatura do C#. E não faz validações e tratamentos de erro.

As variáveis estáticas não fazem sentido porque elas são usadas apenas localmente.

E principalmente tem partes que não fazem sentido.

O erro é [documentado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0176?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

> Static member 'member' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Eu melhorei e cheguei nisso, mas ainda é esquisito e não sei se é o que deseja, a pergunta não descreve o problema adequadamente, dei apenas um jeito de compilar para depois ver os outros erros:

```
using static System.ConsoleColor;
using static System.Console;

namespace GambleGame {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            ForegroundColor = Green;
            Intro();
        }

        public static void Intro() {
            //código do método estático intro
            WriteLine("---------------------------|||Seja bem vindo ao Gamble Game|||---------------------------");
            ResetColor();
            ForegroundColor = Yellow;
            WriteLine("- Intruções:");
            WriteLine("- Digite ''gamble'' para farmar 10 madeiras");
            WriteLine("- Para apostar ''X'' madeiras, digite ''apostar'' e o número de madeiras");
            WriteLine("- Você poderá apostar ''X'' madeiras para ganhar a mesma quantidade");
            WriteLine("- Porém, se você apostar ''X'' madeiras e perder, você perde essa mesma quantidade");
            WriteLine("- Tente ser o maior lenhador dentre seus amigos, boa sorte !");
            WriteLine("- Aperte Enter para começar !");
            ReadLine();
            Clear();
            Start(); //executa o método estático "start"
        }

        public static void Start() {
            ResetColor();
            ForegroundColor = Cyan;
            int madeiras = 0;
            WriteLine("Digite ''gamble'' para bater na árvore");
            WriteLine($"Você possui {madeiras} madeiras");
            while (true) {
                var gamble = ReadLine();
                if (gamble == "gamble") {
                    madeiras += 10;
                    Clear();
                } else {
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("Digite ''gamble'' para bater na árvore");
                }
                if (gamble == $"gamble {madeiras}") {
                    madeiras += madeiras;
                }
                WriteLine($"Você possui {madeiras} madeiras");
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Game.cs).

Comment: Sim, estou ciente do laço infinito, mas essa é a intenção, estou fazendo um jogo que é basicamente um loop com várias condições, portanto, não pretendo sair do laço até eu der a condição de Ganhar ou perder o jogo.